# How to .each_char.map?

Tags: iteration, crystal-lang

In Crystal, if I try this:

```
numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
a = numbers.map { 0 }
p a
```

The output will be nice like this: `[0, 0, 0, 0, 0]`

However if I have a string and try to manipulate each char of that string individually with `each_char` it gets messier

```
word = "NUMBER"
b = word.each_char.map { 'x' }
p b
```

The output will be like this:

```
Iterator::Map(String::CharIterator, Char, Char)(@iterator=#<String::CharIterator:0x7f0040951f50 @reader=Char::Reader(@string="NUMBER", @current_char='N', @current_char_width=1, @pos=0, @error=nil, @end=false), @end=false>, @func=#<Proc(Char, Char):0x453190>)
```

In contrast, Ruby with the same code outputs:

```
["x", "x", "x", "x", "x", "x"]
```

Is there a way to do this to get the same or similar output as Ruby gives in Crystal?

Answer (score 2):

You can collect the iterator's elements into an array using `Iterator#to_a`, which it inherits from [`Enumerable`](https://crystal-lang.org/api/1.1.1/Enumerable.html#to_a-instance-method):

```
p "NUMBER".each_char.map { 'x' }.to_a # => ['x', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x']
```

Alternatively you can start out with an array by using [`String#chars`](https://crystal-lang.org/api/1.1.1/String.html#chars:Array(Char)-instance-method) and then calling `Array#map` on it:

```
p "NUMBER".chars.map { 'x' } # => ['x', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x']
```

This pattern of `each_foo` returning an `Iterator` and `foos` returning an `Array` can be found throughout most of the standard library.